# Remmina blank screen after remote server reboot vnc connection

Tags: vnc, remote, session, remmina

Rebooted remote server running Ubuntu 18.04 and attempted to login using a Remmina VNC connection from an Ubuntu 16.04 client.  Received black screen and nothing else.  Is there an additional configuration option required to start a remote session after restart?

Answer (score 1):

Discovered a monitor must be attached to the remote server for this to work.  Added a dummy plug adapter and all is well.